# Migration from eclipse 3 to eclipse 4 clonePerspective not available

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, perspectives

I am trying to use the compatibility layer to migrate an eclipse 3.5 application to eclipse 4. We use clone perspective to create a new perspective with the same contents with a new id. When I migrate to eclipse 4 clone perspective is not working. On debug, I see that it is not supported. Is there a latest version of any jar I need to include or do I have any alternative to this? Cloning is an integral part of our application and rewriting everything to eclipse 4 is not yet feasible for us.

Comment: Can you expand a bit? Is this a GUI command that has gone or an API call or what?

Comment: I would be interested in that too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384842/eclipse-rcp-cloneperspective-returns-null

Comment: Thanks for the link Terry.