# Eclipse RCP: clonePerspective returns null

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I want to clone a perspective and save that cloned one. However, the call to the [`PerspectiveRegistry.clonePerspective(...)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIPerspectiveRegistry.html) returns null, and I'm running out of ideas what could possibly be wrong with my parameter values.

```
public void savePerspectiveAs(String label) {
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IPerspectiveDescriptor perspectiveDescriptor = perspectiveRegistry
            .findPerspectiveWithLabel(label);

    // if the perspective doesn't exist, create a new one 
    // by cloning the current perspective
    if (perspectiveDescriptor == null) {
        IPerspectiveDescriptor currentPerspectiveDescriptor = 
                perspectiveRegistry.findPerspectiveWithId(currentPerspective);
        // after this line, perspectiveDescriptor is still null
        perspectiveDescriptor = perspectiveRegistry
                .clonePerspective(currentPerspective + "." 
                         + label.replaceAll(" ", "_"), label, 
                         currentPerspectiveDescriptor);
        // hence I get a NullPointerException here...
        connectedPerspectives.add(perspectiveDescriptor.getId());
    }
    page.savePerspectiveAs(perspectiveDescriptor);

}
```

All other values seem to be fine. `currentPerspectiveDescriptor` is a valid object, so is `perspectiveRegistry`.

`label` is something like `"Connected Perspective 2"`. And it does not exist yet, neither does my created perspective ID.

Any ideas? What could go wrong here for `clonePerspective(...)` to return null?

Answer (score 3):

`clonePerspective` is not supported in Eclipse 4.x.

This is the code for `PerspectiveRegistry.clonePerspective`:

```
public IPerspectiveDescriptor clonePerspective(String id, String label,
        IPerspectiveDescriptor desc) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // FIXME: compat clonePerspective. Not called in 3.8
    E4Util.unsupported("clonePerspective"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    return null;
}
```

The Eclipse bug for this is [382209](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382209)

Comment: And instead of throwing an exception it silently logs it - how mean!
Is there any way to work around that, or do we have to wait for the bug fix?

Comment: The bug is over two years old so it is not likely to be fixed any time soon. You could probably do something using the Eclipse e4 EModelService, EPartService, ... personally I haven't looked at perspectives in e4.

Comment: FYI: I asked them, and they told me they do not plan to solve the bug for the next release, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make a workaround for "cloning" a perspective without rewriting everything for e4. However, it's a rather dirty hack, and I don't recommend it, because it uses unchecked casts to Eclipse's implementing classes rather then its interfaces.

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public void savePerspectiveAs(String label) {
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IPerspectiveDescriptor perspectiveDescriptor = perspectiveRegistry
            .findPerspectiveWithLabel(label);

    // if the perspective doesn't exist, create a new one 
    // by cloning the current perspective
    if (perspectiveDescriptor == null) {
        // Note: this is a dirty hack.
        // It is not recommended to cast to PerspectiveDescriptor 
        // or PerspectiveRegistry.
        PerspectiveDescriptor currentPerspectiveDescriptor =
                (PerspectiveDescriptor) perspectiveRegistry.findPerspectiveWithId(currentPerspective);
        perspectiveDescriptor =
                ((PerspectiveRegistry) perspectiveRegistry)
                        .createPerspective(label, currentPerspectiveDescriptor);
        connectedPerspectives.add(perspectiveDescriptor.getId());
    }

    page.savePerspectiveAs(perspectiveDescriptor);
}
```